# How do I write a C++ dictionary to a Lua table?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

I have some C++ code that interacts with some Lua code. Basically, I want to be able to get some results (in the form of a dictionary a.k.a. a collection of items) from a query message and then push them out to Lua as a table so that I can easily access all the results from Lua by using the dictionary.

Right now, I just get one specific value that I want and send that out but it would be nice to send all of them out and not have to request a specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're familiar with the Lua API in general, here's the basic process:

1. Create a new table on the stack ([lua_newtable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_newtable))
2. For each item in the dictionary

   1. Push the value onto the stack
   2. Push the key onto the stack
   3. Call [lua_settable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_settable)

Comment: OK, this makes sense. Can you give me an example of how to easily get the values from the table in LUA code?

Comment: First things first: http://www.lua.org/about.html#name ;) That out of the way, how is your code being triggered? Do you have an existing table in Lua and you call out to C?

Comment: Wow, that's funny that they actually explicitly say not to write it that way. I guess I thought it was an acronym until MrXexxed brought it up.

Comment: I don't have an existing table in Lua, but I'll create one.

Comment: In Lua code:
`for k, v in pairs(MyCFunction(anyargs)) do
    -- k is key, v is value
    DoSomething(k, v)
end`